# Return an instance of a dynamic class

Tags: java, reflection

I'm trying to create a method which receives a class (any class) and return an instance of this class. (It's like "Spring"). How can I do having this code?

Main:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Factory factoria = new Factory();
    Auto auto = factoria.getObject(Auto.class);
    System.out.println(auto.Motor);
}
```

Factory class (getObject is the method that I'm trying to do):

```
public Class<?> getObject(Class<?> clase) throws ClassNotFoundException, InstantiationException, IllegalAccessException{

    Class<?> cls = Class.forName(clase.getName());
    Class<?> objetoRaiz = (Class<?>) cls.newInstance();

    // if @Component
    procesar(objetoRaiz);

    return objetoRaiz;      
}
```

Comment: That isn't a question.  And why are you doing `Class.forName(clase.getName())` when you already have the `Class<?>`?  Or expecting `cls.newInstance()` to return a `Class<?>` instance.

Comment: I'm not pro with Java and Reflection. What is in the code is what i saw on the internet. Sorry, mate.

Comment: How far does your code get?  Or in what way doesn't it work?

Comment: @SteveSmith at Auto auto = factoria.getObject(Auto.class) line. Error: Type mismatch: cannot convert from Class<capture#1-of ?> to Auto.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is best to use the default constructor as that could raise exceptions and in general process something.

```
public <T> T createObject(Class<T> type) throws NoSuchMethodException,
        InstantiationException, IllegalAccessException, InvocationTargetException {   
    return type.getConstructor().newInstance();      
}
```

Or easier on the using side:

```
public <T> T createObject(Class<T> type) throws IllegalArgumentException {   
    try {
        return type.getConstructor().newInstance();      
    } catch (NoSuchMethodException | InstantiationException
            | IllegalAccessException | InvocationTargetException e) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException(e);
    }
}
```

---

***After feedback of Holger:***

There is a common base class of `NoSuchMethodException`, `InstantiationException`, `IllegalAccessException` and `InvocationTargetException`. So nicest is:

```
public <T> T createObject(Class<T> type) throws ReflectiveOperationException  {   
    return type.getConstructor().newInstance();      
}
```

Comment: Since Java 7, you can use `catch(ReflectiveOperationException e)`.

Comment: @Holger I wish I knew that years ago. I took the liberty to add it to the answer as my "API improvement" now only is valid when wishing a runtime exception rather than a checked exception.